# SQL select statement for transforming rows to columns based on their unique values

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

I have the data below in a table named training in an oracle database

```
id dept  usr   tt   em     sk    sal
10  2   user1  ttl1  eml2  skl1  100
10  2   user1  ttl1  eml2  skl2  200
10  2   user1  ttl1  eml2  skl3  300
10  2   user1  ttl1  eml2  skl4  400
20  3   user2  ttl3  eml4  skl1  150
30  4   user3  ttl6  eml8  skl1  100
30  4   user3  ttl6  eml8  skl2  200
30  4   user3  ttl6  eml8  skl3  300
30  4   user3  ttl6  eml8  skl4  400
30  4   user3  ttl6  eml8  skl5  150    
...
and many more rows
```

is there a way to obtain below result with sql select statement?

```
id  dept usr    tt   em   sk1   sal1 sk2  sal2 sk3  sal3 sk4  sal4 sk5  sal5 sk6  sal6
10  2    user1  ttl1 eml2 skl1  100  skl2 200  skl3 300  skl4 300   
20  3    user2  ttl3 eml4 skl1  150
30  4    user3  ttl6 eml8 skl1  100  skl2 200  skl3 300  skl4 400  skl5 150
...
```

Comment: Is the number of skl known in advance?

Comment: There can be upto 10 skl. I have displayed only till sk6 but that can extend till sk10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy way to get the result would be to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression.  I would first query the data and use the windowing function `row_number()` to generate a unique sequence for group of data based on `id`, `dept` and `usr`:

```
select id,
  dept,
  usr,
  tt,
  em,
  max(case when seq = 1 then sk end) sk1,
  max(case when seq = 1 then sal end) sal1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then sk end) sk2,
  max(case when seq = 2 then sal end) sal2,
  max(case when seq = 3 then sk end) sk3,
  max(case when seq = 3 then sal end) sal3,
  max(case when seq = 4 then sk end) sk4,
  max(case when seq = 4 then sal end) sal4,
  max(case when seq = 5 then sk end) sk5,
  max(case when seq = 5 then sal end) sal5,
  max(case when seq = 6 then sk end) sk6,
  max(case when seq = 6 then sal end) sal6
from
(
  select id, dept, usr, tt, em, sk, sal,
    row_number() over(partition by id, dept, usr
                      order by sk) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by id, dept, usr, tt, em;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4d75/2).

Since you are using Oracle 11g, then you could implement the PIVOT and UNPIVOT functions to get the result.  The UNPIVOT will be used to convert your multiple columns of `sk` and `sal` into multiple rows, then you can convert it into your final result using PIVOT.  The syntax will be similar to:

```
with cte as
(
  select id, dept, usr, tt, em, sk, 
    to_char(sal) sal,
    row_number() over(partition by id, dept, usr
                      order by sk) seq
  from yourtable
)
select 
  id, dept, usr, tt, em,
  sk1, sal1, sk2, sal2,
  sk3, sal3, sk4, sal4,
  sk5, sal5, sk6, sal6
from
(
  select id, dept, usr, tt, em, 
    lower(col)||to_char(seq) col, value
  from cte
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (sk, sal)
  ) u
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ('sk1' as sk1, 'sal1' as sal1, 
              'sk2' as sk2, 'sal2' as sal2, 
              'sk3' as sk3, 'sal3' as sal3,
              'sk4' as sk4, 'sal4' as sal4,
              'sk5' as sk5, 'sal5' as sal5,
              'sk6' as sk6, 'sal6' as sal6)
) ;
```

See [SQL FIddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4d75/17). Both give a result:

```
| ID | DEPT |   USR |   TT |   EM |  SK1 | SAL1 |    SK2 |   SAL2 |    SK3 |   SAL3 |    SK4 |   SAL4 |    SK5 |   SAL5 |    SK6 |   SAL6 |
|----|------|-------|------|------|------|------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 10 |    2 | user1 | ttl1 | eml2 | skl1 |  100 |   skl2 |    200 |   skl3 |    300 |   skl4 |    400 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 20 |    3 | user2 | ttl3 | eml4 | skl1 |  150 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 30 |    4 | user3 | ttl6 | eml8 | skl1 |  100 |   skl2 |    200 |   skl3 |    300 |   skl4 |    400 |   skl5 |    150 | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: How can I add another column to the result where it sums up all the values in sal for each user?

Comment: @sian very easy, see [`this demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4d75/18) for the first version and [`this demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4d75/21) for the pivot version.

Comment: I have just one more question- Instead of having SK1 SAL1..SK2 SAL2...and so on in two separate columns, is there a way I can combine those two column values into one column for display purpose?

Comment: @sian You will need to look at using  the LISTAGG function

Comment: @blufeet for some reason it's not identiying LISTAGG

Comment: @sian My suggestion would be to post a new question with the new requirements, it would be much easier then going back and forth in the comments.